# what is this sound effect?

Tags: sound, effects

[I hope you could help me, I'm trying to identify the name of the sound effect used at 1:38 in that video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6wesX_IuKs)

Comment: Sounds like a low frequency (~100 Hz) sawtooth or square wave. Try to generate one with Audacity (Tracks > Add new ... ; Generate > Tone ...). You may also rip the video sound as audio file and inspect it using an audio editor (like Audacity) to find out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, because the sound sample you've provided is very small, but to me it sounds like his last word "oooh" is pitched down a couple of octaves, maybe even one.

Comment: Agreed that's what it is.